# Pygame collision detection less frequent when objects are increased

Tags: collision-detection, sprites, python, pygame

I currently experiencing an issue in pygame where whenever i increase the number of objects e.g. platforms, rocks

```
for a in range(150):
    rock = Rock(0,0)
```

**OR** incresing the range which they spawn in:

```
rock.rect.x = random.randrange(-200,30000)
rock.rect.y = random.randrange(80,500)
rock_list.add(rock)
all_sprites_list.add(rock)
```

**LINE 232**

(which i really need to do for an **ENDLESS** mode) **collision detection between the player and all the objects that have have been changed will become less frequent, so the character will just go through th objects as they weren't even there... you can see the character fall through the objects, it falls through in front of the object and not behind**. All game code is below, I have tried a number of different techniques and values but I have found that these numbers and ranges work best.

Collision Detection code:
 **FOR PLATFORM**

```
medium_collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, medium_list, False)
if medium_collide:
    player.rect.y-=2
```

**FOR ROCK**

```
    rock_collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, rock_list, True)
    if rock_collide:
        lives-=1
    if rock_collide:
        player.rect.y = 100
        player.rect.x = 50
```

***!!!!!GAME CODE BELOW!!!!!***

[**GAME CODE**](http://pastebin.com/ESkBXkhp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't say much without seeing your whole code, but I guess you're just testing collision for all objects in the game. Instead, do a AABB (rectangular) collision test to see if objects are near enough to matter (usually if they are on-screen). If they are, then do your more complex collision detection. Note that this will actually degrade performance extremely if you have all objects of the game on-screen at the same time, and you'll need to adjust this pre-check to fit your game.

Comment: 50%? Depending on his algorithm, anywhere from 0 to x%.

Comment: @Thebluefish Will edit the answer.

Comment: The game code is at the bottom btw and by rectangular collision do you mean: 
if x=y:
#do stuff

Comment: No, I mean something like `if player.x < object.x or player.y < object.y or player.x+player.width > object.x or player.y+player.height > object.y: do stuff`

Comment: How would i spawn say 20 objects and then if their x position is greater than screenwidth, reset at x=0? I have no idea how to control individual objects?

Comment: Keep track of them (by adding them to a list) when they are created, and iterate over that list.

Comment: sorry say for the medium sized platform this is the code whihc controls their x spawning :
medium.rect.x = random.normalvariate(-200,20000)
How would i then do once reached say a smaller range like 500 (instead of 20000), reset back at 0?

Comment: I beleive you should create another question on this site for that, and develop your question a bit more...